# Using Emotion API for Video (Javascript or Ruby)

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax, api, emotion

So I'm working on posting a video to the [Emotion API for video](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/emotion-api) and I haven't been able to get a response.

I've been able to get it to work on the Microsoft [online console](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/emotion-api), but when I try to implement it in my Rails app using (1) JavaScript Ajax, or (2) Ruby server-side code, I consistently get various errors.

Here's my code. At first I tried to Ajax way, but I had a suspicion that the API doesn't have CORS enabled. So then I tried Ruby, to no success.

Ruby attempt:

```
def index
    uri = URI('https://api.projectoxford.ai/emotion/v1.0/recognizeinvideo')
    uri.query = URI.encode_www_form({
    })

    data = File.read("./public/mark_zuck.mov")

    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
    # Request headers
    request['Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key'] = 'e0ae8aad4c7f4e33b51d776730cff5a9'
    # Request body
    request.body = data
    request.content_type = "video/mov"

    response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') do |http|
        http.request(request)
    end

    puts response.body
end
```

Here's my Ajax attempt:

```
    function CallAPI(apiUrl, apiKey){
    console.log("API called");
    $(".loading").css("display", "inline-block");
    $.ajax({
        url: apiUrl,
        beforeSend: function (xhrObj) {
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", apiKey);
        },
        type: "POST",
        data: '{"url": "http://localhost:5000/mark_zuck.mov"}',
        processData: false,
        success: function(response){
            console.log("API success");
            ProcessResult(response);
            $(".loading").css("display", "none");
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log("API failed");
            $("#response").text(error.getAllResponseHeaders());
            $(".loading").css("display", "none");
            console.log(error);
        }
    })
```

Yes, I've regenerated my key. This is just to illustrate my point.

Comment: "*I consistently get various errors*" - define what do you mean by "errors"?

Comment: My ajax attempt yielded a 400 error and also a "Access-Control-Allow-Origin not set" error. My ruby attempt yields `{"error":{"code":"BadArgument","message":"Invalid Media Type."}}`

Comment: Are you sure you're implementing an API client correctly? CORS often prevents the website's code from working elsewhere. Selenium could be used instead  if there's not a working api

Comment: I have the following jsfiddles set up. One is for the [image API](https://jsfiddle.net/nicolairobles/gh6woggf/2/) and the other is for the [video API](https://jsfiddle.net/nicolairobles/ovj4kjL1/4/). The image one works, while the video one does not. This is just the ajax call example.

Answer (score 0):

So you have to set `Content-Type` to application/octet-stream if it's a binary file you're sending, like I was.

If you use a url you should set `Content-Type` to application/json and the url must be publicly available.